# FreeType. How to know number of symbols in FT_Face and its indices?

Tags: c++, freetype

I wanna know all symbols that contains in FT_Face to render its to texture.
FT_FaceRec has  "FT_Long num_glyphs;" but it says me only number of its, but not the indices of its.

I can do something
For (wchat_t c = 0; c < max_value; c++)
  // Load character c here

But in this way I would be have many "rectangles" if the font hasn't the character. That's overhead because its rectangles would be take off area in texture.

How to know glyph_index or wchar_t of characters that font really includes?

Answer (score 2):

May to go through all characters in font face by functions:
FT_Get_First_Char and FT_Get_Next_Char

Example:

```
FT_UInt index;
FT_ULong character = FT_Get_First_Char(face, &index);

while (true) {
  // to do something

  character = FT_Get_Next_Char(face, character, &index);
  if (!index) break; // if FT_Get_Next_Char write 0 to index then
                     // have no more characters in font face
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[freetype wrapper](https://github.com/Gemini2015/freetype-wrapper)

Based on Ogre Font Class, but use more than one texture to store glyphs, each texture has fixed size.